# For which $(a,b)$ is $(round(an),round(bn))$ a 1-1 function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $R(x)$ be the standard rounding function $$R(x)=\lfloor x+\frac12\rfloor$$  It gives the nearest integer to $x$, halves rounding up.

For which $(a, b)\in(0,1)^2$ is the following function one-to-one?
$$f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^2,f(n)=(R(an),R(bn))$$

Let $P$ be the region $$P\subset (0,1)^2:\text {$f$ is 1-1} $$
My progress:
$(\alpha,1-\alpha)\in P$ if $\alpha$ is irrational.  Then halves will never matter, and $R(\alpha n)+R((1-\alpha)n)=n$
The same if $\alpha$ is rational with an odd denominator.
$(\alpha,1-\alpha)\notin P$ if $\alpha$ is rational with denominator $2m$ because $f(m)=f(m+1)$
$(2p/(2m+1),2q/(2m+1))\notin P$ because $f(m)=f(m+1)=(p,q)$.
If $(a,b)\in P$ then so is $(ma,b)$ for any odd integer (or else $ma\ge1$) because you can recover $R(x)$ from $R(mx)$.

The question came up because the New York Times' Spelling Bee has target scores equal to $R(0.4M),R(0.5M)$ and $R(0.7M)$ but the daily maximum score $M$ still can't be deduced if it ends in a $5$ or a $6$.

EDIT:  Here is a graph of rational $(a,b)\in P$ with $a\lt b$ and the common denominator at most $200$.  Some of the lines they lie on have been drawn in.
[image]

Comment: Nice question. Some thoughts though, what is $M$? If $(a, b) \in P$ then for large $m$, $ma$ cannot be in $(0,1) $

Comment: $M$ is $n$.  The question of $f$ being $1-1$ is the same as always being able to deduce $n$, or $M$  from $f(n)$ or $f(M)$.  I was sloppy talking about $ma$.  But if  $ma\gt1$, then $f(n)$ must be $1-1$